# Getting any doc on firestore v9 hanging forever

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a  expressjs backend in combination with firestore to GET data. This line of code used to work and simply returned a list of release version, but the same line of code just hangs indefinitely

```
const querySnapshot = await firestore.getDocs(firestore.collection(db, "releases"));
```

I've tried replacing await with a .then() to see if it returns anything at all, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can you please share your complete code including all the imports and `package.json`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I fixed it, it was a firestore rule problem, I had it on semi test mode where the rule was a date that had already past.

Comment: @ianman18, please post it as an answer so that it would be helpful for other community members with similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @ianman18's comment, the date set in the Firestore rule was already way past.